# Install an Excel COM Add-In with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, comaddin

Is it possible to install a COM add-in using VBA? I've found another post that links to solutions for installing non-COM add-ins using VBA, but that's not working for COM add-ins. Not that it matters, but I'm specifically looking to script the installation of the Inquire COM add-in for Excel 2013.

Here's what I know doesn't work:

This is the code I've found for installing non-COM add-ins:

```
AddIns("NativeShim.InquireConnector.1").Installed = True
```

That code fails because I'm trying to work with a COM add-in and the specified add-in doesn't exist in that collection.

This is the code that I've tried with COM add-ins

```
Dim addin As COMAddIn
Set addin = COMAddIns.Item("NativeShim.InquireConnector.1")
addin.Installed = True
```

That code gets the reference to the add-in correctly but fails on setting Installed to True because COMAddIn objects don't have an Installed property.

Comment: which code have you tried without success?

Comment: @KazJaw I've updated the question with my attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Excel 2010 you need to:

1. Run Excel with Administrator privileges
2. Connect to your add-in instead of setting `.Installed property` in this way:

   ```
   Application.COMAddIns("NativeShim.InquireConnector.1").Connect = True
   ```
3. Setting `.Connect property` to false will obviously turn `com add-in` off.

Comment: Works for 2013 too. Thanks!